# Ajax calls exceeding server's concurrent session limit?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I only find servers with a limit of 20 concurrent sessions (20 requests maximum at the same time).

My application consists of PHP and JS (jQuery). At some point it's making too many Ajax calls back to the server to fetch data from MySQL (16-18 at the same time, and each takes about 3-4 seconds to finish), resulting in a resource limit reached message from the server.

How could I solve this problem without changing my app too much?

In devtool's network the response header for keep alive is `Keep-Alive timeout=5, max=99`.

If I change that to a smaller value, would it help? Or does that only mean if it can not be served in 99 seconds it will close that request?

A solution could be to write a function for all my Ajax calls, which would always wait for a second collecting the calls and do only one request, then it would do a callback to all my functions, making the call but it is a pain to do.

Is there a better and easier solution to this?

Isn't there an option for Ajax calls to limit my concurrent calls to let's say 5, and all the rest would wait until it finishes? Or should i do it with setTimeout manually?

Comment: Might want to consider websockets if you are constantly doing back and forth between client/server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [throttle](https://underscorejs.org/#throttle)/[debounce](https://underscorejs.org/#debounce) techniques.
There are also [jQuery plugins](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) that provides similar functionality